# Consecutive comparisons using if statements inside a while loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I am supposed to compare two consecutive integers, i and j, that are given from a list of integers separated by whitespace which end with a 0 and, if i is less than j, I compare j to max and i to min. If the opposite, I compare j to min and i to max. The output is supposed to be each comparison I do with max, min, i, and j. Additionally, the list must be greater than 2 integers. If it is less then I am supposed to output 0. However the program does not seem to execute the if statements correctly.

```
int i = 1;
int j;
int max = 0;
int min = 0;
int counter = 0;

while (i != 0) {
    cin >> i;

    if (counter == 0) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        i = min;
        j = max;
    } else if (counter == 1) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        i = min;
        j = max;
    } else {
        if (i < j) {
            if (j > max) {
                cout << j << " " << max << endl;
                max = j;
            } 
            if (i < min) {
                cout << i << " " << min << endl;
                min = i;
            }
        } 
        else {
            if (j < min) {
                cout << j << " " << min << endl;
                min = j;
            }
            if (i > max) {
                cout << i << " " << max << endl;
                max = i;
            }
        }
    }
    j = i;
    counter += 1;
}
```

}

Comment: What does it output? What do you expect it to output? Add print statements to find where the mistake is. And then come back if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: I tried it and it ends at the first if statement (counter == 0) and it doesn't execute the later if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `i` (and `j`) in the first iteration of the while loop (`counter == 0`) with `min` which is `0`. As your `while` says `while (i != 0)` you immediately exit, after one `while` iteration. The `if`s should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Input and counter logic can be improved by:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int i;
int j;
int max = 0;
int min = 0;
int counter = 0;
bool flag = true;  // fix the input logic
while (flag){
    cin >>i;
    cin>>j;

    if(i==0 || j==0){
        flag = false;
        break;
    }else{
        counter ++;
        if(counter < 2 ){
            //your code
        }
        else if(i<j){
            cout<<"i: "<<i<<" j: "<<j;
            j = max;
            i = min;
            // your code
        }
        else if(i>j){
            //your code
        }
    }
}


return 0;
}
```